# BackgroundWorker: Block DoWork until ProgressUpdated completes

Tags: c#, .net, multithreading

I have the two functions using a shared variable, and the `BackgroundWorker` is changing it's value before the UI thread can use it.

Is it possible to block the BackgroundWorker's `DoWork` function, while the ui thread updates via `ProgressChanged`?

Or should I just lock the shared variable while it's being used in `ProgressChanged` until the UI thread finishes?

Comment: Why would you want to block the worker thread from finishing as soon as possible? Just report progress less frequently.

Comment: I usually use Waitone.  See msdn : https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/58195swd(v=vs.110).aspx.  You may also want to use a event handler so backgroundwork can notify main thread : https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/11541/The-Simplest-C-Events-Example-Imaginable

Comment: If you do that your background process will be considerably slower

Comment: Have you tried not using a a shared variable? Just pass the variable in RunWorkerCompletedEventArgs

Comment: The background thread is small and merely being used to do a sequential delayed reveal of objects in the gui. In other words, modify a gui object, wait 25ms, modify the next. I am using it to prevent the gui from becoming unresponsive while this happens. However the BackgroundWorker is too fast, and modifying what the variable is pointing to before the gui has a chance to use it which is causing some of the desired changes to be skipped.

Comment: Would it make more sense to set a timer for 25ms (or slightly longer?) and do one modification each time the timer ticks?  If you do that, it will be executed on the ui thread, so you won't have some of the issues that multi-threading presents.  Just a thought.

Comment: Timer seems to be better for what I am trying to do, thanks.

Comment: If not for @ChrisBerger I would tell you that sounds like a design flaw. Definitely, try to use mechanisms that run on UI thread. In this case - timer